# Could not send mail using SMTP In xampp in mac but it works well in windows

Tags: php

Error as below:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error:  Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Are there any firewall restrictions? Are you able to connect to your `SMTP` server without using `PHP` (e.g. by using your mail client)?

Comment: <?php


include "class.phpmailer.php"; 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 456
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mailto = "bijay@techbla.in";
$mail->Username = "bijay@techbla.in";
$mail->Password = "**********";
$mail->SetFrom($email);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $email_message;
$mail->AddAddress("bijay@techbla.in");
 
  if(!$mail->Send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

Comment: yes i can send mail using my mail client

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code. The code in your comment is unreadable.